# This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: root config contains unknown keys: tags

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to run a simple python project on Gitlab. I setup a runner on an EC2 instance and I am trying to use it for the project.
This is the .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
tags:
    - gr
    - grun
    - runner
stages:
    - build
build:
    image: python:3.7
    script:
        - echo "building"
        - pip install -r requirements.txt
        - python test.py
```

I get this error-

```
 This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: root config contains unknown keys: tags
```

I get the same error when I use jobs and environment in the .gitlab-ci.yml file. The runner is active.
How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you see a Ci Gitlab documentation, Tags is not a root config.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `tags` as root element. Only these are allowed [root keywords](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#keywords):

| Keyword | Description |
| --- | --- |
| default | Custom default values for job keywords. |
| include | Import configuration from other YAML files. |
| stages | The names and order of the pipeline stages. |
| variables | Define CI/CD variables for all job in the pipeline. |
| workflow | Control what types of pipeline run. |

If you want to define default tags, you must include a [`default`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#default) section:

```
stages:
  - build
default:
  tags:
    - gr
    - grun
    - runner
build:
  stage: build
  image: python:3.7
  script:
    - echo "building"
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - python test.py
```